# Angular2 - Repeat a call of a service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have a service that retrieves data from server. This data is used to fill a page. I would like to refresh the page every 5 seconds. I tried with a very simple `setInterval()`  but then all the calls to the server are one after the other one without waiting for the previous one to finish. This is a problem when for example the server goes down. I don't know now which one is the best solution, maybe with rxjs and observables.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something simple like this:

```
Rx.Observable.interval(5000)
  .flatMap(() => this.http.whateverYouCall)
  .map(resp => resp.json())
  .subscribe((val) => //do something here with the result)
```

This will make a new call every 5seconds. If you really want to only create a new call 5seconds after the previous one let me know and I'll update this one.

If you only want the next call to start when the previous has ended you could do this:

```
let subject$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject("a");

subject$
  .concatMap(() => fakeHttp().concat(Rx.Observable.empty().delay(5000)))
  .do(() => subject$.next("a"))
  .subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/fufuqid/13/edit?js,console
You'll see that every 7 seconds "b" is logged. 2 seconds for the mocked call and 5 seconds before refreshing.

Comment: yes please.. i would like the next call to start only when the previous one is done

Comment: what would be the way to stop / restart polling? Normally I would use `.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)` where ngUnsubscribe would be a void Subject, which would `.next()`and `.complete()`. However in this case completing a Subject does nothing. I tried to `takeUntil()` before `concatMap()` as well as after `fakeHttp()`, but none of those would stop subscription. :/